# JavaScript error Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list when input value has both " and ' in it

Tags: javascript, forms, double-quotes, coldfusion-11, single-quotes

I am migrating data from DOS dBASE IV to MySQL and I am building an input form using ColdFusion 11. My problem is, as an example, I have a field called 'size' and in it a value of " 2" X 2" X 1/4" X 10' LONG ".

Just one of thousands, so please don't advise me to replace the inch and feet marks with txt.

First I provide a form for selecting fields from the table to display, then provide a form to apply filters and search criteria to the selected fields, then query to get my results.

Because I have a dynamic list of fields I loop over a list of them.
I then replace the ' and then the " so the field value will display in the html input form property.

Everything works except when there is both a ' and a " in the value. Then the JavaScript onBlur function returns an error "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"

```
<!---Coldfusion code --->
<cfloop list="#fcolumnlist#" index="c"> <!---Loop over list of fields selected--->
    <td>
   <cfset thisfield = '#Evaluate('t.#c#')#'> <---Determine the value of the field--->
   <cfset thisfield = Replace(thisfield, '"', "&##34;", "ALL")> <--- replace ' --->
   <cfset thisfield = Replace(thisfield, "'", "&##39;", "ALL")> <--- replace " --->
    
    <input type="text" id="#c##t.id#" name="#c#" value='#thisfield#' 
onfocus="adjWidth(this);" onblur='ck_chg(this, "#thisfield#" )' >
         
    </td>
  </cfloop>
```

My JavaScript functions:

```
function adjWidth(el)  {
        el.style.width =((el.value.length + 10) * 8) + 'px';
 }

function ck_chg(el, v) {
  if ( el.value!=v ) 
    {
        el.style.backgroundColor='#05AD05';
        el.style.color='#FFFFFF';
    } else {
        el.style.backgroundColor='';
        el.style.color='#000000';
    }
}
```

The html source looks like this and displays correctly in the form. BTW: my form can return 1 to over 5,000 records.

```
<input type="text" id="SIZE3137" name="SIZE" value='2&#34; X 2&#34; X 1/4&#34; X 10&#39; LONG' onfocus="adjWidth(this);" onblur='ck_chg(this, "2&#34; X 2&#34; X 1/4&#34; X 10&#39; LONG" )' >
```

I have tried almost every possible combination of replacing the inch and feet marks but nothing has worked. I have tried just using textarea which displays easier but I could not get the style and the JavaScript to function like I want. BTW; the function `adjWidth()` is because of the unknown widths of the unknown columns, it works, ugly but it works.

How can I improve or at least make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that after the HTML has been parsed, and the HTML entities have been resolved, the JavaScript engine will have to deal with parsing the code. This `onblur` code will now look like this:

```js
ck_chg(this, "2" X 2" X 1/4" X 10' LONG" )
```

...and there we see the problem: the string literal is closed immediately after the first "2", and the rest becomes a syntax error.

One quick workaround is to rely on the `value` attribute that already has the desired string value. So the `onblur` could be set like this:

```html
   <input type="text" id="#c##t.id#" name="#c#" value='#thisfield#' 
          onfocus="adjWidth(this);" 
          onblur='ck_chg(this, this.getAttribute("value") )' >
```

Another possibility is to escape the double quotes that appear inside the JavaScript string literal (again), but then with JS escapes, i.e. with a backslash. So:

```html
  <cfset thisfield = Replace(thisfield, '"', "&##34;", "ALL")> <--- replace ' --->
  <!--- add this variant: the quote is also escaped for JS --->
  <cfset thisfield2 = Replace(thisfield, '"', "\\&##34;", "ALL")> 
  <cfset thisfield = Replace(thisfield, "'", "&##39;", "ALL")> <--- replace " --->
  <input type="text" id="#c##t.id#" name="#c#" value='#thisfield#' 
         onfocus="adjWidth(this);" onblur='ck_chg(this, "#thisfield2#" )' >
```

---

Please also consider using [`EncodeForHTMLAttribute`](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-e-g/encodeforhtmlattribute.html) for escaping HTML instead of doing it "manually" with `Replace` calls.

And finally, this kind of string manipulation makes code hard to maintain. Although it would be a non-trivial effort, consider moving all that JavaScript code away from HTML attributes, and instead attach event handlers via JavaScript code that resides in `<script>` tags. This is considered better practice, and results in less character escaping head aches.

Comment: 'Sweet' as my great grandson says.  this.getAttribute("value"), worked perfectly. Thanks so much. I also replaced the cfset(s) with the EncodeForHTMLAttribute.  I read about that but I misunderstood the description so I didn't even try it.  After I get the ajax working to update the MySQL table I plan on adding the event Listeners.  Thanks.